# Uso e significato di "narrazione"

Tags: word-usage

Ho l'impressione, correggetemi se sbaglio, che il termine "narrazione" sia sempre più usato, e forse abusato, da qualche tempo a questa parte.  La narrazione sembra essere sempre meno quella delle storie  di Rodari e sempre più quella giornalistica, di fatti e avvenimenti che, forse per essere più incisici, vengono non solo descritti, ma "narrati" come ad una  ipotetica platea.
A conferma, anche se solo parziale, di questa mia impressione c'è  [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=narrazione&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnarrazione%3B%2Cc0) che mostra  un visibile aumento del termine  dagli anni '70. Ma l'impressione che io ho si riferisce non solo alla carta stampata ma anche, anzi soptrattutto, al linguaggio usato spesso  in televisione dove tra telegiornali vari e programmi di attualità il termine sembra essere molto usato.

Esempi da programmi televisivi sono difficili da fornire, per cui includo alcuni esempi scritti come:

Da "[Una nuova narrazione del mondo](https://books.google.it/books?id=ycJywu8a6UMC&pg=PA19&dq=%22narrazione%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixqtSO-pHPAhXFPRoKHb-kDnEQ6AEIQTAH#v=onepage&q=%22narrazione%22&f=false)" di Riccardo Petrella:

> - Il sistema dominante non ha dimenticato questa lezione ***e ha creato una nuova narrazione della storia,*** una nuova retorica per raccontare e legittimare il suo dominio e quanto ... (2007)

Da [Dentro la televisione](https://books.google.it/books?id=gpVXHAUt80cC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=narrazione%20della%20cronaca%20televisiva&source=bl&ots=MW22dzMnTH&sig=nDBKgimwc670KNjpwDsozk_vgIo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin5_q2-5HPAhXBAxoKHQz0Bz0Q6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q=narrazione%20della%20cronaca%20televisiva&f=false) Gian Maria Corazza:

> - Non è d'altronde il presente ***il momento della narrazione e della cronaca televisiva?***  La memoria "assoluta" (che poi è memoria del mezzo e non di chi lo utilizza) e l'informazione "istantanea"... (1999)

Domanda:

C'è veramente nella quotidianità un sensibile incremento dell'uso di questo termine? E se sì, l'uso contemporaneo di "narrazione" ha in qualche misura subito una mutazione semantica rispetto a quello più tradizionale?

Comment: «l'uso contemporaneo di "narrazione" ha in qualche misura subito una mutazione semantica...?» Non ho capito: che mutazione avrebbe subito? Che cosa significherebbe adesso? Non si parla sempre di narrare eventi, che siano fiabe, leggende o fatti di cronaca?

Comment: @DaG - sì certo, ma a me sembra che l'uso in rifermento a fatti o notizie piuttosto che a fiabe e leggende sia più recente. O mi sbaglio?

Comment: @xxxxxx Credo che la cosa recente sia la distinzione tra *fatti o notizie* e *fiabe e leggende*.

Comment: Intuisco cosa dici, xxxxxx, ma non sono sicuro di avere le idee chiare (neanche con me stesso, dico). Ho anch'io la vaga impressione di qualche cambiamento o estensione del significato, come se con “narrazione” si intendesse anche una sorta di interpretazione, un senso da dare alle cose, un contesto più ampio, per esempio per unificare vari fatti che di per sé sono o sembrano slegati. La prima citazione che porti, per esempio, sembra andare in questo verso. Intendi qualcosa del genere?

Comment: Credo che il significato contemporaneo a cui fai riferimento, sia la trasposizione italiana del termine inglese "storytelling". http://www.panorama.it/news/marco-ventura-profeta-di-ventura/che-cosa-e-storytelling/

Comment: @DaG - si, "narrare"  la storia dei tre porcellini non penso sia lo stesso "narrare"  di un fatto di cronaca nera ad esempio. La mia impressione è che ci sia stata una estensione dell'uso del termine ma che al tempo stesso abbia assunto una connotazione un po' diversa come hai notato. Mi chiedo se sia veramente così o se questa "narrazione" riferita a fatti o cose reali esistesse e fosse comune già in passato, nell'Ottocento o primo Novecento ad esempio quando quotidiani e settimanali erano già in circolazione anche se non così diffusi.

Comment: @WalterVilla - penso che la stesso sua avvenuto nella lingua inglese, con l'estensione dell'uso e significato di "story-telling". Potrebbe essere che abbiamo importato questo uso dalla lingua inglese?

Comment: Credo di sì. A memoria, nell'abito del design storytelling è usato da tempo,   narrazione, in questa accezione, mi sembra più recente. Però sono solo impressioni.

Comment: c'è anche _narrative_ che mi sembra sia la parola che verrebbe usata per tradurre in inglese il tuo primo esempio, cioè un modo di presentare i fatti.
Es. sui migranti ci sono delle _narratives_ in competizione tra loro sui media, anche se i fatti da presentare sono gli stessi. 
Quindi non so se è la parola storytelling che sta influenzando l'italiano, o se è l'inglese, o se è una cosa che sta succedendo per caso. 

Notare che in america hanno notato l'uso aumentato di queste parole: 
http://www.chron.com/opinion/outlook/article/Clarence-Page-New-buzzword-in-political-circles-1713596.php